# how to past a value that dont cross with table is SAS EG

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, cross-join, enterprise-guide

I have two tables :

- First one with client_id and shop_id: each client has several shop_id that he visited.
- Second one with all shop_id.

I need to get random shop_id that client had visited from table_1 (it may be min(shop_id from table_1)

And random shop_id that client had **NOT** visited from table_2.
Seems than cross join can help:

```
proc sql;
select a.client_id, min(a.shop_id) as id_1, min(b.shop_id) as id_2
    from table_1 a, table_2 b
where a.shop_id <> b.shop_id
group by 1
;quit;
```

But the problem is that tables are huge and this approach will take infinitely much time.
Can you help?

Comment: What's the rough ratio of `shops` to `customer shop visits`? Are there 10,000 shops and an average customer only visits 3? Or are there 10 shops and an average customer visits 8?

Comment: rather 10,000 shops and an average customer visits 10

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `left join`:

```
select min(cs.shop_id) as visited_shop_id,
       min(case when cs.shop_id is null then a.shop_id end) as not_visited_shop_id
from all_shops a left join
     client_shops cs
     on cs.shop_id = a.shop_id and
        cs.client = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using the `Except` operator, to subtract the set of visited shops from the set of all client/shop pairs (assuming you also have a `clients` table). If you want to exclude clients who haven't visited any shops or who have visited all shops, simply change the two `left joins` to regular `joins`.

```
proc sql;
    create table unvisited_shops_updated as
        select  c.client_id,
                u1.first_unvisited_shop,
                v1.first_visited_shop
        from clients c
        left join ( /* For each client, get the first shop_id they havn't visited */
            select  u.client_id,
                    MIN(u.shop_id) as first_unvisited_shop
            from (
                select  c.client_id, /* Get list of all client/shop combinations */
                        s.shop_id
                from clients c
                cross join shops s

                except /* Remove client/shop combinations that have been visited */

                select  v.client_id,
                        v.shop_id
                from client_shop_visits v
            ) u
            group by u.client_id
        ) u1
            on u1.client_id = c.client_id
        left join ( /* For each client, get the first shop_id they have visited */
            select  v.client_id,
                    MIN(v.shop_id) as first_visited_shop
            from client_shop_visits v
            group by v.client_id
        ) v1
            on v1.client_id = c.client_id
        order by c.client_id
    ;
run;
```

Here's the performance I get on my PC using the below test script:

Original query execution time: 32.53 seconds CPU time

Updated query execution time: 0.10 seconds CPU time

Full test script is below.

```
%let shop_count = 1000;
%let client_count = 100;
%let visit_count = 50000;

data shops;
    do shop_id = 1 to &shop_count;
        output;
    end;
run;

data clients;
    do client_id = 1 to &client_count;
        output;
    end;
run;

data client_shop_visits;
    do visit_id = 1 to &visit_count;
        client_id = rand("Integer", 1, &client_count);
        shop_id = rand("Integer", 1, &shop_count);
        output;
    end;
run;

proc sql;
    create table unvisited_shops_original as
        select a.client_id, min(a.shop_id) as id_1, min(b.shop_id) as id_2
            from client_shop_visits a, shops b
        where a.shop_id <> b.shop_id
        group by 1
    ;
run;

proc sql;
    create table unvisited_shops_updated as
        select  c.client_id,
                u1.first_unvisited_shop,
                v1.first_visited_shop
        from clients c
        left join ( /* For each client, get the first shop_id they havn't visited */
            select  u.client_id,
                    MIN(u.shop_id) as first_unvisited_shop
            from (
                select  c.client_id, /* Get list of all client/shop combinations */
                        s.shop_id
                from clients c
                cross join shops s

                except /* Remove client/shop combinations that have been visited */

                select  v.client_id,
                        v.shop_id
                from client_shop_visits v
            ) u
            group by u.client_id
        ) u1
            on u1.client_id = c.client_id
        left join ( /* For each client, get the first shop_id they have visited */
            select  v.client_id,
                    MIN(v.shop_id) as first_visited_shop
            from client_shop_visits v
            group by v.client_id
        ) v1
            on v1.client_id = c.client_id
        order by c.client_id
    ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to filter out shops that clients didn't visit, then run

```
monotonic()
```

it will get numerate your shops that customers never visited -- then do the same for clients, and simpy join them

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_FISH AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.Species, 
          /* birds_monotonic */
            (monotonic()) AS birds_monotonic
      FROM SASHELP.FISH t1;


CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_CARS AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.Make, 
          t1.Model, 
          t1.Type, 
          /* cars_monotonic */
            (monotonic()) AS cars_monotonic
      FROM SASHELP.CARS t1;


CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_FISH_0000 AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.Species, 
          t1.birds_monotonic, 
          t2.Make, 
          t2.Model, 
          t2.Type, 
          t2.cars_monotonic
      FROM WORK.QUERY_FOR_FISH t1
           LEFT JOIN WORK.QUERY_FOR_CARS t2 ON (t1.birds_monotonic = t2.cars_monotonic);
QUIT;
```